Scope 3.11 - Open Source Software
My company has an open source software deployment. How would we go about reporting Scope 3.11  emissions "Products that directly consume energy (fuels or electricity) during use". We have no way of knowing how much they are using the software so calculating electricity is unrealistic.

Your product do not directly consume energy. So it should be optional (https://ghgprotocol.org/sites/default/files/2022-12/Chapter11.pdf) and I would say you should ev. consider only the product you sell (estimate how much your client will use your program), the rests are just benefit for the world)
